# RequireJS Randomly Break

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm trying to create a site using Jquery Mobile, Backbone and RequireJS. But the problem I am having is the site randomly break and reasons why the break are different:

- JQuery is Undefined
- Backbone is Undefined
- Extended views of backbone are not defined
- etc etc etc

And I cannot pinpoint our the reason why because it works sometimes but when I refresh it, it suddenly doesn't. I'm loading my code like this(libraries followed by views):

```
requirejs(["/js/libs/jquery-1.8.3.min", "/js/libs/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min", "/js/libs/underscore-1.4.3", "/js/libs/json2", "/js/libs/backbone.0.9.9"], function($,JQM, underscore, json2, bb) {

});

requirejs(["/js/views/pageview", '/js/views/home'], function(util) {

    HomeView = new HomeView({el : '#home', 'id' : 'home'})
});
```

Am I doing something wrong by doing it this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Libraries like jQuery Mobile, Backbone and Underscore are not AMD modules, just plain old javascript files. And because they're not modules, they don't declare dependencies, they just expect to find `$` or `_` in the global scope.

The loading order of RequireJS is indeterministic - so there's no telling which of them will load first. If Backbone is evaluated first, it won't find the `window._` it's looking for and crashes.

RequireJS supports non-AMD modules via the shim config ([see docs](http://www.requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim)), which allows you to declare the dependencies between these libraries. After configuring the shim, RequireJS knows how to load the dependent libraries before those that depend on them.

A typical RequireJS config with the shim element would look something like:

```
requirejs.config({
  //libraries
  paths: {
      jquery:       'libs/jquery/jquery',
      backbone:     'libs/backbone/backbone',
      underscore:   'libs/underscore/underscore',
      jquerymobile: 'libs/jquery.mobile-1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0',
  },

  //shimming enables loading non-AMD modules
  //define dependencies and an export object
  shim: {
      jquerymobile: {
          deps: ['jquery'],
          exports: 'jQuery.mobile'
      },
      underscore: {
          exports: '_'
      },
      backbone: {
          deps: ['jquerymobile', 'jquery', 'underscore'],
          exports: 'Backbone'
      }
  }
});
```

The `paths` part is not mandatory, you could just use the file paths as keys in the `shim` section. However, when you use the `paths` aliases, you can then import those libraries with the short name instead of the whole path:

```
define(['jquery', 'backbone'], function($, Backbone) { ... });
```

Comment: jQuery exposes itself as an AMD module, does it not? (As of jQuery 1.7)